# Not modifying a loaded node module

Tags: node.js, javascript

In my Node app, have a config file like this:

```
module.exports = {
    BUILD_DIR: '/some.path',
    OTHER_CONFIG: 42,
    // ...
};
```

I also have some tests doing things like

```
var appConfig = require('./path/to/appConfig');
appConfig.BUILD_DIR = 'tmp/some/path';
// and stuff done with appConfig
```

To my big surprise doing this apparently modifies the state of the module. My next test that requires it will have `BUILD_DIR` set to 'tmp/some/path'. I did not realize modules had this kind of state across requires. How do I get rid of this effect in my test? Also, how can I prevent people from modifying the state of this module? If someone includes it, they should always get what it defines, and not possibly something some other code wrote to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why [is explained here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to `require('foo')` **will get
>   exactly the same object returned**, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.

(emphasis mine)

So the object that you're exporting is cached and shared among the code that uses it.

If that's not what you want, you could export a function instead:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return {
    BUILD_DIR: '/some.path',
    OTHER_CONFIG: 42,
    // ...
  };
};
```

And `require` it like so:

```
var appConfig = require('./path/to/appConfig')();
```

Comment: This does not actually work, I still end up with my modification showing up in my other test. If I do "return extend({}, {..config..})" in the function, then it does work.

Comment: I've tested it and it works for me ([gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/c58a3da939d6c18d07aa)). It should, because the object returned by the function is newly created each time the function is called, even if the function itself is cached.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I was putting the config in a var and then returning that via the function. Doing this in one step works as advertised.

Comment: @JeroenDeDauw ah right, if you're returning the same var each time, you're just passing along a reference to the same object :) (`extend` creates a new object too, so that's why that route worked as well)

Comment: I'm mainly a PHP dev, used to "associative arrays" that do not get passed by reference :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your module is called 'Config', and you originally:

```
var Config=require('Config');
```

you could:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('Config')];
```

which will remove the module from require's cache, causing it to be loaded afresh when you next 'require' it.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/raisch/6786930

Comment: Interesting. This however does put the responsibility with all the callers to do this delete when they need to. Bit error prone, and the caused errors are likely to not be very local.

Comment: Actually, the only affect of doing the above is to be able to reload the module. The original load is still available after the cache deletion so the only possible side effect would be if you changed something particularly important to system operation in a non-compatible way.